# Java - JWebBrowser can't load new points to map

Tags: javascript, java, json, swing, jwebbrowser

I added to JPanel [JWebBrowser](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html). I load html-file with js that load map and json-file with point coordinates as:

```
webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
final JPanel webPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
webPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
webBrowser.navigate(WebServer.getDefaultWebServer()
          .getClassPathResourceURL(getClass().getName(), "index.html"));
```

I created a button that update json-file and load new point coordinates in this file. Then I try to refresh the page in the browser to set new points on the map, but jwebbrowser updates only the html-file and js-script, and doesn't load new json-file and as a result old points are marked on the map. If I close the program and open again - everything is ok, there is new points.

So, my problem: how to load the updated json-file with new coordinates of points?

I tried this:

```
webBrowser.reloadPage();
```

and I tried jwebbrowser disposing and creating new jwebbrowser, but everything is ineffectual:

```
            webBrowser.disposeNativePeer();
            webPanel.removeAll();
            webPanel.revalidate();
            webPanel.repaint();

            webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
            webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
            webBrowser.navigate(WebServer.getDefaultWebServer().
                    getClassPathResourceURL(getClass().getName(), "index.html"));
            webPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            webPanel.revalidate();
            webPanel.repaint();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (maybe for somebody it will be useful):

```
WebServer.stopDefaultWebServer();
```

It's not necessary to drop JWebBrowser, better way:

```
WebServer.stopDefaultWebServer();
WebServer.getDefaultWebServer();
webBrowser.navigate(WebServer.getDefaultWebServer()
                        .getClassPathResourceURL(getClass().getName(), "index.html"));
```